# Should I perform both lemmatization and stemming?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, stemming

I'm writing a text classification system in Python. This is what I'm doing to canonicalize each token:

```
lem, stem = WordNetLemmatizer(), PorterStemmer()
for doc in corpus:
    for word in doc:
        lemma = stem.stem(lem.lemmatize(word))
```

The reason I don't want to just lemmatize is because I noticed that `WordNetLemmatizer` wasn't handling some common inflections. In the case of adverbs, for example, `lem.lemmatize('walking')` returns `walking`.

Is it wise to perform both stemming and lemmatization? Or is it redundant? Do researchers typically do one or the other, and not both?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/basic-nlp-with-nltk ("Stemming and Lemmatization" section)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317418/stemmers-vs-lemmatizers.

Answer (score 6):

From my point of view, doing both stemming and lemmatization or only one will result in really SLIGHT differences, but I recommend for use just stemming because lemmatization sometimes need 'pos' to perform more presicsely.

For example, if you want to lemmatize "better", you should explicitly indicate pos: print(lemmatizer.lemmatize("better", pos="a"))

If not supplied, the default is "noun"

Answer (score 2):

The lemmatization of *walking* is ambiguous. Walking, when used as an adjective, is its own baseform (rather than walk).

**Correction**:
Research has shown that generally stemming outperforms lemmatization in IR tasks.
A qualitative comparison between the two and an explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11177381/9412325).

Comment: May I ask what is "IR" tasks?

Comment: @theEconCsEngineer [Information retrieval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval).

Answer (score 1):

I think stemming a lemmatized word is redundant if you get the same result than just stemming it (which is the result I expect). Nevertheless, the decision between stemmer and lemmatizer depends on your need. My intuition said that steamming increses recall and lowers precision and the opposite for a lemmatization. Consider this scores, what matter for your specific problem? Other option talking about this scores is to calculate F-1 score which is the harmonic average of the precision and recall.